# Prove that $\frac{1}{f\circ g} = \frac{1}{f} \circ g$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I have to prove or disprove this:
$$\frac{1}{f\circ g} = \frac{1}{f}\circ g$$
or 
$$\frac{1}{f\circ g} = f \circ \frac{1}{g}$$

I know that for the first if $f=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g=0$
then we can undefined for the $LHS$ and $0$ for the $RHS$.

The second is a bit easier but I'm having trouble formulating the prove, well disprove actually for both.

Comment: You need to properly specify domain and codomain for this to be a well-posed problem and any sensible choice will eliminate the "undefined" example as that is just a result of imprecision; also note that both sides are undefined for the choice you give.

Comment: Does it seem like there is any reason it should be true?

Comment: The first is true.  $\frac 1f\circ g(x)=\frac 1{f(g(x))}$ and $\frac 1{f\circ g}(x)= \frac 1{f\circ g(x)}= \frac 1{f(g(x))}$.  But the second is just nuts.  $f\circ 1{g}(x)=f\circ 1{g(x)} = f(\frac 1{g(x)})$ but $\frac 1{f\circ g}(x)= \frac 1{f\circ g(x)}= \frac 1{f(g(x))}$. Those aren't the same.

Answer (score 1):

Big picture:

Composition is not reversible.  $h\circ j \ne j\circ h$ in general.

But it is associative.   $h\circ (j\circ k) = (h\circ j)\circ k$ because... well, you *only* are going in order.  If $k(x) = y$ and $j(y) = w$ and $h(w) =z$ then $[(h\circ j)\circ k](x) = (h\circ j)(k(x)) = (h\circ j)(y) = h(j(y))= h(w) = z$

while $[h\circ (j\circ k)](x) = h([j\circ k](x))=h(j(k(x))) = h(j(y))=j(w) = z$.

It's almost impossible to imagine how it is not.

....

Soooooo.... if $h(x) =\frac 1x$ then

$\frac 1{f\circ g} = h\circ (f\circ g) = (h\circ f)\circ g = \frac 1f \circ g$.

But $f\circ \frac 1g = f\circ h \circ g\ne h\circ f\circ g = \frac 1{f\circ g}$.

.......

If that is glib then just shove an elments into them and see what happens.  Let $g(x)=y$ and $f(y) = w$ then $\frac 1{f\circ g}(x) = \frac 1f\circ g(x) = \frac 1w$..... it works.

But

$f\circ \frac 1g(x) = f\circ \frac 1y$ and if we let $f(\frac 1y) = v$ and

$\frac 1{f\circ g}(x) = \frac 1{f(g(x))} =\frac 1{f(y)} = \frac 1w$.  The is utterly *no* reason that $\frac 1w = \frac 1{f(y)}$ should be equal to $v=f(\frac 1 y)$.

Coming up with a counter-example should be easy.  Just find an $f$ and $y$ where $f(\frac 1y)\ne \frac 1{f(y)}$ and a $g$ and $x$ were $g(x) = y$.

$g(x) = x+3$ and $f(y) = x^2 +5$ then $f\circ \frac 1g = (\frac 1{x+3})^2 + 5$ whereas $\frac 1{f\circ g} = \frac 1{(x+3)^2 + 5}$ for example.

Comment: just out of curiosity, the notation $\frac{1}{f\circ g}$ is necessarily informal, right? I mean...it doesn't make any sense to talk of a "fractional set of ordered pair" (where $f\circ g$ is the set of ordered pairs) . Only $\frac{1}{f\circ g (x)}$ makes technical sense, yes?

Comment: It's no more or less informal than the notation $\frac 1f$ is.  I don't think is informal.